# Migrating specific folders from SVN to Git

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, svn2git

I have an SVN repo which looks like this:

- Trunk:

  - dir_1
  - dir_2
  - dir_3
  - dir_4
  - dir_5
  - dir_6

and I wish to Migrate only directories dir_1,dir_2 and dir_5 to a new Git repository including all the branches, and history of those directorys.
so that the outcome will be:

- master:

  - dir_1
  - dir_2
  - dir_5

Is that possible?

Comment: Where do the branches live?

Comment: Is this about a one-time migration and you only use Git afterwards, or do you want to commit back to SVN from the Git clone?

Comment: this is a one-time migration and the intention is to use Git only after that migration..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git-svn` is **not** the right tool for one-time conversions of repositories or repository parts. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are plenty tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

You will be easily able to configure `svn2git`s rule file to produce the result you want.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

You see, there are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use git-svn with the `--include-paths` option:

```
git svn clone <svn url> --trunk=Trunk --include-paths="dir_1\/|dir_2\/|dir_5\/" --no-metadata
```

The input to `--include-paths` is regex so make sure it does not match additional folders in the repository. Use the `--no-metadata` flag only if you will not commit to the svn repository again.

Comment: Doing this, however, will include the entire SVN commit history of Trunk in the git log. What if I only want the commit histories of dir_1, dir_2 and dir_5 in the git log?